# Problem with enumerate in Texstudio

Tags: enumerate, texstudio

I used to use the next code in Overleaf

```
\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries P\arabic*.}]
\item
\end{enumerate}
```

With the package enumitem. I tried to use the same code un Texstudio but doesnt works. The first error I get is

```
Missing number, treated as zero.
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
```

and then a lot of error en the "\item", Do you have any clue what can be? A tried to use the package enumerate too, but still fails.

Comment: texstudio is just the editor you are using to write the file, any errors or pdf output come from tex and are not related top the editor you use. If you get an error please post a small _complete_ document that produces the error so people can debug it for you.

Answer (score 1):

The error is unrelated to the editor you use (texstudio)

This document

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries P\arabic*.}]
\item zzz
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Produces the error that you state:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \c@* 
l.6 \begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries P\arabic*
                                                .}]
?
```

Uncommenting the `enumitem` line to load that package makes it run without error.